# Best constant for Sobolev inequality from Sobolev space to Hölder space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $u(x) \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that the Sobolev embedding from $W^{1,p}(U)$ to $C^{0,\alpha}(U)$ holds for some $n$, $p$, $\alpha$ and bounded domain $U$. We have the Sobolev inequality
$$ \|u\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(U)} \leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}. $$
I am wondering how the constant $C$ depends on the domain $U$. Suppose $u$ is bounded and take maximum value at the origin. It is obvious that $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_1)}\leq \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_4)}$ and
$$ \|u\|_{C^{0}(B_1)} \leq C_1 \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_1)}, \quad \|u\|_{C^{0}(B_1)}=\|u\|_{C^{0}(B_4)} \leq C_4 \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_4)}.$$
So I expect that $C_1$ should be larger than $C_4$ as the LHSs are the same, but $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_4)}$ on the RHS of the second seems larger. Is there any explicit relation of $C$ on the domain?

Comment: If $\alpha = 1 - p/n$ then $C$ is uniformly bounded (by $2\sqrt n/\alpha$ according to my lecture notes). The standard proof for this embedding is surprisingly constructive, and you should be able to find a good upper bound of $C$ by keeping track of the constants in the proof, which should not be too hard. You could check the proof in Evans book.

Comment: @daw thank you for the comment. Does it mean that for the special value of $\alpha$ you mentioned, the constant is independent of the domain?

Comment: It means only that $C$ is bounded independently of $\Omega$. If $\alpha$ is different then I would expect that $C$ scales with some power of the diameter of $\Omega$. This can be tracked in the usual proof as well.  I would expect that $C$ depends on $\Omega$.

Comment: It is wired to me. If $\|u\|_{C^0(B_r)} \leq \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_r)}$ (just put the constant to be one for simplicity) in the case you mentioned, then as $r \to 0$ the RHS should be zero. But I think $u$ can be non-zero at the origin. Is there any mistake I made?

Comment: You are right. That is no contradiction to what I wrote.

Comment: But I think that a constant function $u(x)=1$ on $B_1$ is in both $C^{0,\alpha}(B_1)$ and $W^{1,p}(B_1)$, but $\|u\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_r)}=1$ and  $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_r)}\to 0$ as $r \to 0$. So $\|u\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_r)}\leq \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B_r)}$ is not true?

Comment: Oh, I see my error: my claims were made for $W^{1,p}_0$ not $W^{1,p}$. You are right with all you remarks.